# Qt: how do I highlight duplicated items in QListWidget? (qtjambi)

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, qt-jambi

I need to implement a mechanism of highlighting duplicated values. Values are edited through delegate depending on the value type (string - line edit, long and big decimal - spin boxes). Currently, I implemented this feature with help of additional class which stores all values and their counts in two "parallel" lists. And after adding a new value I increase its count number (or decrease when repeated value is removed), but this solution seems to be too bulky. Do you guys have any other ideas on highlighting in `setModelData(...)` method of QItemDelegate?

```
/**
* Stores a delegates' existing values
*/
private final class DelegateValuesStorage {
    private final List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private final List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ....

    //Add value or increase a count if exists
    public void add(final Object value) {
        if(values.contains(value)) {
            final int valueIndex = values.indexOf(value);
            final int oldCount = counts.get(valueIndex);
            counts.remove(valueIndex);
            counts.add(valueIndex, oldCount + 1);
        } else {
            values.add(value);
            counts.add(1);
        }
    }

    ....

    //Decrease a count or remove value if it doesn't exist anymore
    public void decreaseCount(final Object value) {
        if(value == null) {
            return;
        }
        final int index = values.indexOf(value);
        if(index >= 0) {
            final int oldCount = counts.get(index);
            if(oldCount >= 2) {
                counts.remove(index);
                counts.add(index, oldCount - 1);
            } else {
                values.remove(index);
                counts.remove(index);
            }
        }
    }

/**
* Delegate
*/
private class ConcreteDelegate extends QItemDelegate {

    private final DelegateValuesStorage values = new DelegateValuesStorage(); 

    ...

    @Override
    public void setModelData(final QWidget editor, final QAbstractItemModel model, final QModelIndex index) {
        if(editor instanceof ValEditor) { // ValEditor is an abstraction of line edit and spin box over values' data types

            final Object value = ((ValEditor) editor).getValue();
            model.setData(index, value, Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole);
            final String newData = (value == null) ? "" : String.valueOf(value);
            values.add(newData);
            final String oldData = (String) model.data(index, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole);
            values.decreaseCount(oldData);


            model.setData(index, newData, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole);
            model.setData(index, new QColor(0, 0, 0), Qt.ItemDataRole.ForegroundRole);
            redrawItems(model); // runs through values and colors them red if count >= 2; or black if count == 1

        } else {
            super.setModelData(editor, model, index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use maps for those kinds of tasks:

```
private final class DelegateValuesStorage {
    private final Map<Object, Integer> values = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();

    ....

    //Add value or increase a count if exists
    public void add(final Object value) {
       Integer count = values.get(value);
       if (count == null) {
          values.put(value, 1);
       } else {
          values.put(value, count + 1);
       }
    }

    ....

    //Decrease a count or remove value if it doesn't exist anymore
    public void decreaseCount(final Object value) {
        if(value == null) {
            return;
        }
        Integer count = values.get(value);
        if (count == null) {
            // decreasing a "new" value - could be an error too
            return;
        }
        if (count <= 1) {
            // remove the value from the map
            values.remove(value);
        } else {
            values.put(value, count - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Highlighting now should be enabled if

```
values.get(value) > 1
```

is `true`.